# Неизвестный элемент "top" в скрипте. Исправить ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую вот такой скрипт для подсветки меню при прокрутке на лендинге. Все работает, но браузер ругается. Говорит, что

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Как можно избавиться от этой ошибки, как решить?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#left-header a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top - 400 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#left-header li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта -

```
console.log(currLink.attr("href"));
var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
```

выборка `$(currLink.attr("href"))` - пустая:

```
if (refElement.length == 0)
  return;
```

или выборка не пустая, но элемент в ней - невидимый:

```
if (!refElement.position())
  return;
```

Вместе:

```
if (refElement.length == 0 || !refElement.position())
  return;
```